# How to create subsequent data based on the first row？

Tags: r

I want to generate subsequent data based on the first row of data, how to do it. I did it using a for loop, but it's too slow. Like this.
The initial dataframe is：

```
DataORI <- tibble(
  Year = c(2010:2015),
  Age = rep(60,length(c(2010:2015))),
  Wage = rep(1000,length(c(2010:2015)))
)
```

```
Year  Age  Wage
2010  60   1000
2011  60   1000
2012  60   1000
```

**My goal is：**

```
Year  Age  Wage
2010  60   1000
2011  61   1000
2012  62   1000
2011  60   1000
2012  61   1000
2013  62   1000
2012  60   1000
2013  61   1000
2014  62   1000
```

Of course, my data has longer years and ages and more columns. How to do it to improve efficiency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use `crossing`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
DataORI %>% 
   select(-Age) %>%
   crossing(Age = 60:62)
```